# How can I disable the back browser button after user press logout and destroy session?

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble with `session_destroy()`.

When the User press *Log out* it have to destroy the session. I wrote the following code:

***Logout.php***

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header("location: LoginViewController.php");
?>
```

After pressing *log out*, when I press the browser back button it is showing my previous Logined user page and session username in *Login.php* page

***Login.php***

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user']=  $_GET['username'];
    echo '"<div style="background:white; text-align:right"> Login as:'.$_SESSION['user'].'</div>"';
    echo '<a href="Logout.php" style="text-align:right">Logout</a>';
```

***LoginViewController.php***

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

    $Username = $_POST['uname'];
    $Password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $User_Type=$_POST['type'];

    If (!(empty($Username) && empty($Password) && empty($User_Type))){
        $model = new UsersModel();
        $rowsCount = $model->checkUser($Username,$Password,$User_Type);

        if ($rowsCount!=0){
            header("location:login.php?username=".$_POST['uname']."");  
        } else {
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Enter username and password correctly");
            window.location.href="LoginViewController.php";</script>';
        }
    }
```

I don't know why it is working like that.

Please help me to find out where I commit mistake.

I want to disable that browser back button after logout.

Comment: This should help you : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout

Comment: is the user being passed around in the url via Parameters?  And do you really mean to set the user in the session to something sent in by the user?

Comment: yes, i passed the username through url and get that username to display on my page..

Comment: your session is recreated when you press the back button.

Comment: yeah, but how can i restrict that one...

Comment: Session is not recreated at all. Does anyone read the answers ? o_o

Comment: @KvkGanesh The answer of Fabio should work but did you take a look at this ? http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout

Comment: Why do you want to disable the browser back button?

Comment: Actually you just can't really disable the browser back button, but you can force the browser to "revalidate" the page by executing server side code. Then by executing the code, you can redirect the user if it has no session set.

Comment: @Brewal I tried the code form Fabio but again it is going back and showing the  previous logged in page.. while clicking on browser back button..

Comment: You must put this code on each page you want to revalidate. Not just your login page. And don't forget to empty your browser cache after doing this.

Comment: @Brewal As you said i placed the code in my Login pages,but again it is going back and showing the previous logged  page

Comment: Where do you put your code ? You have to put it above everything, especially html code (including doctype)

Comment: @Brewal I put that code in php tag above my html... in every page

Comment: Did you empty your browser cache ?

Comment: @Brewal How can i do that please tell me...

Comment: What is your browser ?

Comment: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-clear-firefox-cache

Comment: @Brewal As you said i done that by using that link but again it is going back...

Comment: I see in your logout code : `header("location: LoginViewController.php");`. Here you forgot the upper case 'L' for 'Location'. Is this a typo ?

Comment: @Brewal I changed that one but no positive result..

Comment: This just have to work. You probably are mistaken somewhere. Can you provide more code as it is now ?

Comment: @Brewal Ok..... that means paste the code what i am using in my login pages here..

Comment: Wait... I think I understand what you are trying to do. Your Login.php should not echo anything. It should redirect you to some kind of content page. Do you have a form to pass your username ?

Comment: @Brewal This is the form i am using in my Loginpage                 <form name='f1' method="POST" action="" >

Comment: Answer edited. You messed up everything buddy :)

Comment: @Brewal Thankyou for quick replying..but when i clicked the browser back button after logout it showing some msg like document expaired..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

login.php page :

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['uname'], $_POST['pwd'], $_POST['type'])) {
        $Username = $_POST['uname'];
        $Password = $_POST['pwd'];
        $User_Type=$_POST['type'];
        if (!(empty($Username) || empty($Password) || empty($User_Type))) 
        {
             $model = new UsersModel();
             $rowsCount = $model->checkUser($Username,$Password,$User_Type);
             if ($rowsCount!=0)
             {
                  $_SESSION['user'] = $Username;
                  header("Location:LoginViewController.php");

             } else {
                  echo 'Bad user';
             }
        } else {
             echo 'Please, fill all inputs';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Bad form sent';
    }
?>
<form name="f1" method="POST" action="" >
    // inputs
</form>
```

LoginViewController.php :

```
<?php
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
echo 'You have successfully logged as '.$_SESSION['user']
?>
```

And add the headers to force the browser to revalidate the pages :

logout.php :

```
<?php 
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array();
header("location: login.php");
?>
```

Comment: @KvkGanesh add `$_SESSION = array();` in your logout script

Comment: I cleared the browser cache but it is going back after logout.. I don't know why? Is there any alternative...

Comment: @KvkGanesh the name of your file `LoginViewController.php` suggest that you are using a framework... What is it if so ?

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by the browser cache that is keeping details in the page, if you refresh the page or you move any further in your private area you will be prompted to login page and you will not be able to see anything, assuming that your login check system is correctly configured.

You can otherwise force the browser to not cache the page and have a new request to the server for the page

```
header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");
```

Comment: I used those header's in my Logout.php but it is not working again it's going back

Comment: @kvk what happen if you move inside protected area?

Comment: As Brewal said I Placed your code in my  all my login page but not working again it is going back...

Comment: Do you check if user is logged in all protected pages?

Comment: you need to use isset on a $_SESSION parameter like username, or something which is stored in session when user is logged

Answer (score 2):

You should do a redirect from your logout script.

For example:

```
header("Location: index.php");
```

You if user hits back next time, it'll go to the logout.php page again, where you can do the check again and redirect again :) It's an infinite loop if the user tries again.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (window.history) {
window.history.forward(1);
}
```

Comment: @KvkGanesh this is javascript and unsecure. You should not use this.

Comment: @Brewal Do you have any solution? this is what i use for my problem.

Comment: @KvkGanesh Once you logout your page redirects somewhere so put this code in that page.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");
```

Answer (score 0):

***Here is my LoginController.php***

```
  <?php

     header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
     header("Pragma: no-cache");
     header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");
```

//If you are submitting the form insert the details into database

```
   $Username = $_POST['uname'];
    $Password = $_POST['pwd'];
    $User_Type=$_POST['type'];
    session_start();

   If (!(empty($Username) && empty($Password) && empty($User_Type))) 
   {

    $model = new UsersModel();

    $rowsCount = $model->checkUser($Username,$Password,$User_Type);

    if ($rowsCount!=0)
    {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $Username;
       header("location:login.php");

    } else 
        {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Enter username and password correctly");
        window.location.href="LoginViewController.php";</script>';
           }
        }

    }
     ?>
```

***Here is my after Login page(login.php).. and displays the session user name  and logout link***

```
    <?php

      header("Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
      header("Pragma: no-cache");
      header("Expires: Fri, 4 Jun 2010 12:00:00 GMT");

      session_start();
     if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
     {
       header('Location: LoginViewController.php');
        exit();
       }
      echo '"<div style="background:white; text-align:right"> Login as:'.$_SESSION['user'].'
       <a href="Logout.php" style="text-align:right">Logout</a></div>"';
        ?>
```

***Here is my Logout.php***

```
   <?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
     session_start();
      session_destroy();
      header("Location: LoginViewController.php");
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on all pages except login page and login validation page.

```
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['sesuname']) {
    echo "You are not logged in.";
    exit();
} else {    
    /* All other codes must be here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I stopped backing up in Chrome:
I use this function:

```
function do_html_url($url) {
echo '
    <html>  
    <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">    
      window.location.replace("'; echo $url; echo '");  
      </script>
      <noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript</noscript>
      </body>
      </html>';
return;
}
```

Then, in index.php (first page of my site) I set a switch to 0; and in the "before" page test if the switch is zero, and if not return control to index.php by calling the function above as do_html_url("index.php"). In the "after" page, set the switch to 1, which will cause the "before" page to reject an attempt to back up to it.

Example:

1. In my first page (index.php): $_SESSION['needoffersw']=0;
2. In my later "before" page: if ($_SESSION['needoffersw']!=0) {do_html_url("index.php");}
3. In my "after" page: if ($_SESSION['needoffersw']!=0;