# Laravel pop-up on session

Tags: php, session, laravel

I got anoying bug in my laravel 5.0 application. I hardcoded pop-up into my view file and it appears only if session is set. For example:

```
@if (Session::has('global'))

    POP-UP

@endif
```

Session with name error is set on post method, like this:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password ], $remember))
                    return redirect('/user/user-status');
else 
                    return redirect()->back()->with('global', 'Invalid email or password');
```

Example:

If i type in wrong password pop-up appears with message invalid username or password. If I type right password appilaction log's me in. The problem is that if I click back ,in my browser, after loging in application will return me to log in page with same pop up. As I understand session does not reset, that's why pop-up appears. Could you suggest me any solution to avoid it? Thanks!

Example 2:

I write a blog post, after successfully creating new blog post pop-up appears `YOUR BLOG POST HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY CREATED`. If i click for exapme Home and after I click back button in my browser same pop-up appears again (becouse last session is still set) `YOUR BLOG POST HAS BEEN SUCCESSFULLY CREATED`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
You have to flush session key on successfull login or redirection like this:

```
Session::forget('global');
```

[For more information click here(same problem with browser backbutton)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961202/how-can-i-disable-the-back-browser-button-after-user-press-logout-and-destroy-se)

Comment: Do I do this in controller method, where session is set?

Comment: when you are success full loged in.Then after back in your browser session already remove flash message named global,Thats means no pop-up will genearate on successfull login

Comment: Yes it's a solution, but this case I have to protect all the get routes. I have like 50 of them.

Comment: what i am trying to say is.I didn't say you have to remove all cookie name because you have to protect all the get route,But reality is that particular named session will be destroyed.

Comment: On blog post page first remove session variable and then try to reintilize that.