# How to stop user from going back to admin pages once logged out in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to stop user to visit previous wp-admin pages once he logs out.

Is there a way to disable cache on admin pages or to redirect the user to login page once the user is logged out and press back button?

Answer (score 0):

Add following snippet to your theme’s `functions.php` file:

```
add_action('wp_logout','auto_redirect_external_after_logout');
function auto_redirect_external_after_logout(){
  wp_redirect( 'https://example.com/specific-page-once-the-user-is-logged-out' );
  exit();
}
```

**Edit**:

- [How can i disable the back browser button after user press logout and destroy session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961202/how-can-i-disable-the-back-browser-button-after-user-press-logout-and-destroy-se)
- https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout -

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kris, but I want to disable back button once you log out. Your code is for redirecting the user to some other page.

Actually, the scenario is once you log-out from wp-admin you are redirected to the wp-login.php. But if you press back button on the browser previous page get's open again from the cache. I want to stop user to access previous admin pages once he logs out.

Hope I am clear.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961202/how-can-i-disable-the-back-browser-button-after-user-press-logout-and-destroy-se and https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/549347/Browser-Back-Button-Issue-After-Logout - good luck :)